# Why is RenderControl called when a Control's Visible property is set to false?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've put a breakpoint on my Control's overridden [RenderControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htwek607.aspx) method and the breakpoint is being hit, but in Visual Studio, I can see that `this.Visible` is `false`.

In the documentation for the [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx) property it says:

> If this property is false, the server control is not rendered.

This doesn't necessarily mean the `RenderControl` method is not called, but it's a big hint that it shouldn't do. Should I be jumping out of the method manually if `Visible` is false? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accorging to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx):

> Before rendering, view state is saved for the page and all controls.
>   During the rendering stage, the page calls the **Render method for each
>   control**, providing a text writer that writes its output to the
>   OutputStream object of the page's Response property.

And as you can see from the diagramm below, `RenderControl` is a part of Render process:
[image]

So it call the method `RenderControl` regardless `Visible` prop value. It's your responsibility to output empty string or anything based on `Visible` property.